# JS fiddle React js external resource issue

Tags: reactjs, dependencies, jsfiddle, codesandbox

**Here is my sandbox**
[React Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/81p55r4l02)

I want to implement same thing in js fiddle. i have tried jsfiddle external resource to import dependency .but its not working. I need a fiddle with the dependencies that are mentioned in package.json of code sand box link. Is this possible to implement it  same sandbox in jsfiddle if yes then please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Hi Irfan, the 'React Example' link isn't working, can you fix it ?

Comment: plz check now,its working now